# Code values in new column based on whether values in another column are unique

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following data I would like to create a new column `new_sequence` based on the condition:
If only one `id` is present the new value should be 0. If several `id`'s are present, the new value should numbered according to the values present in `sequence`.

```
dat <- tibble(id = c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4),
               sequence = c(1,1,1,2,3,1,2))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
     id sequence
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        1
2     2        1
3     3        1
4     3        2
5     3        3
6     4        1
7     4        2
```

So, for the example data I am looking to produce the following output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id sequence new_sequence
  <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1        1            0
2     2        1            0
3     3        1            1
4     3        2            2
5     3        3            3
6     4        1            1
7     4        2            2
```

I have tried with the code below, that does not work since all unique values are coded as 0

```
dat %>% mutate(new_sequence = ifelse(!duplicated(id), 0, sequence))
```

Comment: Try adding `group_by(id) %>%` before your `mutate()`.

Comment: I reckon that does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dplyr::add_count()` rather than `!duplicated()`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  add_count(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_sequence = ifelse(n == 1, 0, sequence)) %>%
  select(!n)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id sequence new_sequence
  <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1        1            0
2     2        1            0
3     3        1            1
4     3        2            2
5     3        3            3
6     4        1            1
7     4        2            2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following. After grouping by `id` check if the number of rows in the group `n()` is 1 or not. Use separate `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse` since the lengths are different within each group.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new_sequence = if(n() == 1) 0 else sequence)
```

**Output**

```
     id sequence new_sequence
  <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1        1            0
2     2        1            0
3     3        1            1
4     3        2            2
5     3        3            3
6     4        1            1
7     4        2            2
```